# Tile underlayment, Ditra vs wire mesh lath

Tags: tiling, underlayment

My previous kitchen tiles were laid on top on wire mesh and mortar. Except for a few smaller grout cracks they were relatively okay and flat. After removing the tiles, mortar, and mesh I have discovered that the plywood is sagging/flexing in some areas which I will try to fix by securing it with screws.

However, as per underlayment, I am not sure if I should go again with wire mesh or Ditra would be a better option when it comes to preventing possible cracks?

Answer (score 1):

"Except for a few smaller grout cracks they were relatively okay and flat"; Ditra is *primarily* a water blocking membrane. If you believe that the "sagging/flexing plywood" was caused by water penetration, then an upgrade to the water resistance of your assembly is in order.

**However**, mortar and mesh provide a function unrelated to Ditra; it is to provide a strong and flat substrate to support the tile installation.

I recommend **both**! Ditra to waterproof the plywood, then cement tile-board *or* a mortar bed to provide a strong surface to place your tile on.